# Swift class introspection & generics

Tags: introspection, swift

I am trying to dynamically create a `class` instance based type using generics, however I am encountering difficulty with class introspection.

Here are the questions:

- Is there a Swift-equivalent to Obj-C's `self.class`?
- Is there a way to instantiate a class using the `AnyClass` result from `NSClassFromString`?
- Is there a way to get `AnyClass` or otherwise type information strictly from a generic parameter `T`? (Similar to C#'s `typeof(T)` syntax)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24069875/292145 gives some hints on the Swift reflection API.

Comment: Objective-C's `self.class` would become `self.dynamicType.self` in Swift I belief

Comment: In an instance method, here's how to call a class method: `self.dynamicType.foo()`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Well, for one, the Swift equivalent of `[NSString class]` is `.self` (see [Metatype docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1022), though they're pretty thin).

In fact, `NSString.class` doesn't even work! You have to use `NSString.self`.

```
let s = NSString.self
var str = s()
str = "asdf"
```

Similarly, with a swift class I tried...

```
class MyClass {

}

let MyClassRef = MyClass.self

// ERROR :(
let my_obj = MyClassRef()
```

Hmm… the error says:

> Playground execution failed: error: :16:1: error: constructing an object of class type 'X' with a metatype value requires an '@required' initializer
>
> ```
>  Y().me()
>  ^
>  <REPL>:3:7: note: selected implicit initializer with type '()'
>  class X {
>        ^
> ```

It took me a while to figure out what this means… turns out it wants the class to have a `@required init()`

```
class X {
    func me() {
        println("asdf")
    }

    required init () {

    }
}

let Y = X.self

// prints "asdf"
Y().me()
```

Some of the docs refer to this as `.Type`, but `MyClass.Type` gives me an error in the playground.

Comment: Thank you for your link to the Metatype docs! I totally overlooked that aspect of Types, doh!

Comment: You can use `.Type` or `.Protocol` in variable declaration, e.g. `let myObject: MyObject.Type = MyObject.self`

Comment: Sulthan: so MyObject.Type is a declaration but MyObject.self is a factory method (can be called) and myObject is a variable containing a reference to a factory method.  The call myObject() would produce an instance of class MyObject.  It would be better example if the name of myObject variable was myObjectFactory?

Comment: `@` before `required` should be deleted

Answer (score 49):

Here's how to use `NSClassFromString`. You have to know the superclass of what you're going to end up with. Here are a superclass-subclass pair that know how to describe themselves for `println`:

```
@objc(Zilk) class Zilk : NSObject {
    override var description : String {return "I am a Zilk"}
}

@objc(Zork) class Zork : Zilk {
    override var description : String {return "I am a Zork"}
}
```

Notice the use of the special `@obj` syntax to dictate the Objective-C munged name of these classes; that's crucial, because otherwise we don't know the munged string that designates each class.

Now we can use `NSClassFromString` to make the Zork class or the Zilk class, because we know we can type it as an NSObject and not crash later:

```
let aClass = NSClassFromString("Zork") as NSObject.Type
let anObject = aClass()
println(anObject) // "I am a Zork"
```

And it's reversible; `println(NSStringFromClass(anObject.dynamicType))` also works.

---

**Modern version:**

```
    if let aClass = NSClassFromString("Zork") as? NSObject.Type {
        let anObject = aClass.init()
        print(anObject) // "I am a Zork"
        print(NSStringFromClass(type(of:anObject))) // Zork
    }
```

Comment: Upvote for the `@objc(ClassName)` bit. I knew about the `@objc` attribute but not that you could also give a hint about the class name.

Comment: Excellent solution that still works more or less as written 6 years on.  Just a couple minor tweaks the playground asked for: `as! NSObject.Type` in the first line and `aClass.init()` in the second

Answer (score 13):

If I'm reading the documentation right, if you deal with instances and e.g. want to return a new instance of the same Type than the object you have been given and the Type can be constructed with an init() you can do:

```
let typeOfObject = aGivenObject.dynamicType
var freshInstance = typeOfObject()
```

I quickly tested it with String:

```
let someType = "Fooo".dynamicType
let emptyString = someType()
let threeString = someType("Three")
```

which worked fine.

Comment: Yep, `dynamicType` works as I expected there. However, I have been unable to compare types. The real big use is with generics, so I could have something like `Generic<T>` and inside `if T is Double {...}`. It seems that is not possible unfortuantely.

Comment: @SiLo Did you ever find a way to ask in general whether two objects are of the same class?

Comment: @matt Not elegantly, no I did not. However, I was able to create a `Defaultable` protocol which works similar to C#'s `default` keyword, and proper extensions for types like `String` and `Int`. By adding the generic constraint of `T:Defaultable`, I could check if the argument passed `is T.default()`.

Comment: @SiLo Clever; I'd like to see that code! I take it that this gets around the strange limitations on the use of "is". I've filed a bug on those limitations, and also on the general lack of class introspection. I ended up comparing strings using NSStringFromClass, but of course that only works for NSObject descendants.

Comment: @matt Unfortunately it sounds more clever than it really is because you still have to do `value is String.default()`... etc, which you would just end up doing `value is String` instead.

Answer (score 13):

In **swift 3**

```
object.dynamicType
```

is deprecated.

Instead use:

```
type(of:object)
```

Answer (score 7):

### **Swift implementation of comparing types**

```
protocol Decoratable{}
class A:Decoratable{}
class B:Decoratable{}
let object:AnyObject = A()
object.dynamicType is A.Type//true
object.dynamicType is B.Type//false
object.dynamicType is Decoratable.Type//true
```

**NOTE:** Notice that it also works with protocols the object may or may not extend

Answer (score 1):

Finally got something to work. Its a bit lazy but even the NSClassFromString() route did not work for me...

```
import Foundation

var classMap = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

func mapClass(name: String, constructor: AnyObject) -> ()
{
    classMap[name] = constructor;
}

class Factory
{
    class func create(className: String) -> AnyObject?
    {
        var something : AnyObject?

        var template : FactoryObject? = classMap[className] as? FactoryObject

        if (template)
        {
            let somethingElse : FactoryObject = template!.dynamicType()

            return somethingElse
        }

        return nil
    }
}


 import ObjectiveC

 class FactoryObject : NSObject
{
    @required init() {}
//...
}

class Foo : FactoryObject
{
    class override func initialize()
    {
        mapClass("LocalData", LocalData())
    }
    init () { super.init() }
}

var makeFoo : AnyObject? = Factory.create("Foo")
```

and bingo, "makeFoo" contains a Foo instance.

The downside is your classes must derrive from FactoryObject and they MUST have the Obj-C +initialize method so your class gets automagically inserted in the class map by global function "mapClass".

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example showing class hierarchy implementation, similar to accepted answer, updated for the first release of Swift.

```
class NamedItem : NSObject {
    func display() {
        println("display")
    }

    required override init() {
        super.init()
        println("base")
    }
}

class File : NamedItem {
    required init() {
        super.init()
        println("folder")
    }
}

class Folder : NamedItem {
    required init() {
        super.init()
        println("file")
    }
}

let y = Folder.self
y().display()
let z = File.self
z().display()
```

Prints this result:

```
base
file
display
base
folder
display
```

Comment: This technique does not work correctly if the variable is the superclass's Type. For example, given `var x: NamedItem.Type`, if I assign it `x = Folder.Type`, then `x()` returns a new `NamedItem`, not a `Folder`. This renders the technique useless for many applications. I consider this [a bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5796632348065792).

Comment: Actually you can do what I think you want using this technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290469/create-a-swift-object-from-a-dictionary/26290606#26290606