# How do I access a class property by string in Swift?

Tags: swift

Let's say I have 5 `SKLabelNode`s. Each is named incrementally. `myLabel0`,`myLabel1` etc... They are all added to a `SKScene`. How do I set and get the label with a string. Something like:

```
for i in 0..5 {
 self["mylabel\(i)"].text = "Label \(i)"
}
```

I know that in other languages you can do things similar to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Swift support reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060667/does-swift-support-reflection)

Comment: You can't. Use an array instead. There are languages that support reflection but it's never the preferred way to do things.

Comment: Explanation of the downvote? Does this question not show any research effort? Is it unclear? It is not useful? I've never heard of reflection.

Comment: I do not see any downvotes (maybe someone downvoted and someone else upvoted or the downvoter changed his mind). There are two votes for closing as duplicate. I disagree with them because reflection is not the only way to do what you want to do. It would be in Swift, but there are languages that can do it with no need for actual reflection.

Answer (score 1):

An `SKScene` is a subclass of `SKNode` and nodes form a tree through parent/child relationships.  Rephrased, your question is 'how can I access a child of a SKNode using subscript notation with a string index'.

As such

```
extension SKNode {
  subscript (name: String) -> SKNode? {
    return self.childNodeWithName (name)
  }
}
```

If `name` is not a child of `self`, then perhaps you'd want to recurse on the children.