# How to get class properties label in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get class properties label in runtime. for example,
I have this class:

```
 class BasicD {
     public var id_: Int64 = 0
     public var a: Int32 = 0
     public var c: NSData?
     public var d: NSData?
   }
```

I need to output to be: [id_,a,c,d]

I want somthing like reflection in java. I know mirror do like reflection, but for geting class properties in mirror I should initialize class first, but I do not want to do that.

Comment: Please explain more about this....I little bit understand..

Comment: You want to get all the variable of your class ?

Comment: yes i want to get all the variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844681/list-of-classs-properties-in-swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463146/iterate-over-object-class-attributes-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Mirror in swift3 to get all the properties of a class like this

```
class BasicD{
    public var id_: Int64 = 0
    public var a: Int32 = 0
    public var c: NSData?
    public var d: NSData?
}

let obj = BasicD()
var arrayOfObjects: [String] = []
let mirror =  Mirror(reflecting: obj)
for child in mirror.children {
    guard let key = child.label else { continue }
    arrayOfObjects.append(key)
    print(key)
}
print(arrayOfObjects)
```

Here `arrayOfObjects` contains all your variable name of class `BasicD`

Comment: `Mirror(reflecting: obj).children.flatMap{$0.label}` is Swifter...