# Turn swift object into a JSON string

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I have classes like these:

```
class MyDate
  {
    var year : String = ""
    var month : String = ""
    var day : String = ""

    init(year : String , month : String , day : String) {
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
    }

}
```

---

```
class Lad
{
    var firstName : String = ""
    var lastName : String = ""
    var dateOfBirth : MyDate?

    init(firstname : String , lastname : String , dateofbirth : MyDate) {
        self.firstName = firstname
        self.lastName = lastname
        self.dateOfBirth = dateofbirth
    }
}
```

---

```
class MainCon {

    func sendData()  {


        let myDate = MyDate(year: "1901", month: "4", day: "30")
        let obj = Lad(firstname: "Markoff", lastname: "Chaney", dateofbirth: myDate)

        let api = ApiService()
        api.postDataToTheServer(led: obj)

    }

}
```

---

```
class ApiService {

    func postDataToTheServer(led : Lad)  {
        // here i need to json
    }
}
```

And I would like to turn a `Lad` object into a JSON string like this:

> {
>       "firstName":"Markoff",
>       "lastName":"Chaney",
>       "dateOfBirth":
>       {
>           "year":"1901",
>           "month":"4",
>           "day":"30"
>       }
>   }

Comment: @vadian could you help me please

Comment: are you using some JSON framework?, with SwiftyJSON is easy to achieve what you need

Answer (score 4):

EDIT - 10/31/2017: This answer mostly applies to Swift 3 and possibly earlier versions. As of late 2017, we now have Swift 4 and you should be using the [Encodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) and [Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) protocols to convert data between representations including JSON and file encodings. (You can add the [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) protocol to use both encoding and decoding)

The usual solution for working with JSON in Swift is to use dictionaries. So you could do:

```
extension Date {
  var dataDictionary {
    return [
      "year": self.year,
      "month": self.month,
      "day": self.day
    ];
  }
}

extension Lad {
  var dataDictionary {
    return [
      "firstName": self.firstName,
      "lastName": self.lastName,
      "dateOfBirth": self.dateOfBirth.dataDictionary
    ];  
  } 
}
```

and then serialize the dictionary-formatted data using `JSONSerialization`.

```
//someLad is a Lad object

do {
  // encoding dictionary data to JSON
  let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: someLad.dataDictionary, 
                                                   options: .prettyPrinted)

  // decoding JSON to Swift object
  let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
  // after decoding, "decoded" is of type `Any?`, so it can't be used
  // we must check for nil and cast it to the right type        
  if let dataFromJSON = decoded as? [String: Any] {
      // use dataFromJSON
  }
} catch {
    // handle conversion errors
}
```

If you just need to do this for few classes, providing methods to turn them into dictionaries is the most readable option and won't make your app noticeably larger.

However, if you need to turn a lot of different classes into JSON it would be tedious to write out how to turn each class into a dictionary. So it would be useful to use some sort of reflection API in order to be able to list out the properties of an object. The most stable option seems to be [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection). Using EVReflection, for each class we want to turn into json we can do:

```
extension SomeClass: EVReflectable { }

let someObject: SomeClass = SomeClass();
let someObjectDictionary = someObject.toDictionary();
```

and then, just like before, we can serialize the dictionary we just obtained to JSON using `JSONSerialization`. We'll just need to use `object.toDictionary()` instead of `object.dataDictionary`.

If you don't want to use `EVReflection`, you can implement reflection (the ability to see which fields an object has and iterate over them) yourself by using the [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror) class. There's an explanation of how to use Mirror for this purpose [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463146/iterate-over-object-class-attributes-in-swift).

So, having defined either a `.dataDictionary` computed variable or using `EVReflection`'s `.toDictionary()` method, we can do

```
class ApiService {

  func postDataToTheServer(lad: Lad)  {
    //if using a custom method
    let dict = lad.dataDictionary

    //if using EVReflection
    let dict = lad.toDictionary()

    //now, we turn it into JSON
    do {
      let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, 
                                                       options: .prettyPrinted)
      // send jsonData to server
    } catch {
      // handle errors
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: thanks you so much .. could check my update question I am sorry for my bad

Answer (score -1):

May this GitHub code will help you.

```
protocol SwiftJsonMappable {
   func getDictionary() -> [String: Any]
   func JSONString() -> String
}



extension SwiftJsonMappable {

//Convert the Swift dictionary to JSON String
func JSONString()  -> String {
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self.getDictionary(), options: .prettyPrinted)
        // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        // here "decoded" is of type `Any`, decoded from JSON data
        return jsonString
        // you can now cast it with the right type

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return ""

}

//Convert Swift object to Swift Dictionary
func getDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    var request : [String : Any] = [:]
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    for child in mirror.children {
        if let lable = child.label {
            //For Nil value found for any swift propery, that property should be skipped. if you wanna print nil on json, disable the below condition
            if !checkAnyContainsNil(object: child.value) {

                //Check whether is custom swift class
                if isCustomType(object: child.value) {
                    //Checking whether its an array of custom objects
                    if isArrayType(object: child.value) {
                        if let objects = child.value as? [AMSwiftBase] {
                            var decodeObjects : [[String:Any]] = []
                            for object in objects {
                                //If its a custom object, nested conversion of swift object to Swift Dictionary
                                decodeObjects.append(object.getDictionary())
                            }
                            request[lable] = decodeObjects

                        }
                    }else {

                        //Not an arry, and custom swift object, convert it to swift Dictionary
                        request[lable] = (child.value as! AMSwiftBase).getDictionary()
                    }
                }else {
                    request[lable] = child.value
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return request
}

//Checking the swift object is swift base type or custom Swift object
private func isCustomType(object : Any) -> Bool {

    let typeString = String(describing: type(of: object))
    if typeString.contains("String") || typeString.contains("Double") || typeString.contains("Bool") {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

//checking array
private func isArrayType(object : Any) -> Bool {

    let typeString = String(describing: type(of: object))
    if typeString.contains("Array"){
        return true
    }
    return false
}

//Checking nil object
private func checkAnyContainsNil(object : Any) -> Bool {
    let value = "\(object)"
    if value == "nil" {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

}
```

https://github.com/anumothuR/SwifttoJson