# Get name of function from reference to it

Tags: swift, reflection

Given the following, Is it possible to use some sort of reflective mechanism in Swift/Obj-C to get the string "foo" from the reference `bar`?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060667/does-swift-support-reflection) and some other SO posts, but they seem to be focused on apply reflection to classes, not lone functions.  I saw `method_getName`, but I don't know how to translate a Swift function to a Method object.

```
func foo(p1:Any, p2:String) -> Int {
    return -1
}
func getName(fn:Any) -> String {
    return // name of fn
}
print(getName(fn))
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. This would require language changes. Why do you want this anyways?

Comment: Not possible. It's very hard to find some real word usage.