# Create a Swift Object from a Dictionary

Tags: ios, dynamic, swift

How do you instantiate a type dynamically based upon a lookup value in a dictionary in Swift?

Comment: Unfortunately you've now edited the question out of all recognition. It is no longer clear what the question was or what this is the solution to. It would be better to revert to the original question and put the answer as an answer, not as an edit of the question that overwrites the original question.

Comment: Yeah, isn't really a question anymore. I made it into a question now, is that better? Or should I go back?

Comment: Essentially you can't do it at all in Swift. However you can do it in Objective-C and Swift is perfectly capable of interacting with Objective-C objects. Note that anything subclassing NSObject is not a swift object, it is an Objective-C object. They behave mostly the same, but Objective-C ones are able to be dynamic, but have other drawbacks (eg: they're much slower).

Comment: Abhi, In my test, removed the NSObject as a base class and it still works.

Comment: Even after editing, this "question" is still a question containing an answer.  That is, the code example in the "question" doesn't demonstrate a problem, but is the answer to the problem.  The Answer below doesn't provide an answer, but a comment on the answer contained in the question.  I suggest editing the "question" so that it is obvious to readers that it was edited and that it is self-answering.   Help readers by following conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I don't remember exactly what I wrote when I first asked the question. So hopefully this edit, where I moved the answer to the answer section, makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this is useful to others. It took some research to figure this out. The goal is to avoid the anti-pattern of giant if or switch statements to create each object type from a value.

```
class NamedItem : CustomStringConvertible {
    let name : String

    required init() {
        self.name = "Base"
    }

    init(name : String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    var description : String { // implement Printable
        return name
    }
}

class File : NamedItem {
    required init() {
        super.init(name: "File")
    }
}

class Folder : NamedItem {
    required init() {
        super.init(name: "Folder")
    }
}

// using self to instantiate.
let y = Folder.self
"\(y.init())"

let z = File.self
"\(z.init())"

// now put it in a dictionary.
enum NamedItemType {
    case folder
    case file
}

var typeMap : [NamedItemType : NamedItem.Type] = [.folder : Folder.self,
                                                  .file : File.self]
let p = typeMap[.folder]
"\(p!.init())"
let q = typeMap[.file]
"\(q!.init())"
```

> Interesting aspects:
>
> - use of "required" for initializers
> - use of .Type to get the type for the dictionary value.
> - use of .self to get the "class" that can be instantiated
> - use of () to instantiate the dynamic object.
> - use of Printable protocol to get implicit string values.
> - how to init using a non parameterized init and get the values from subclass initialization.

Updated to Swift 3.0 syntax

Comment: I found this enlightening.  Thanks for sharing your research.