# Swift - Initialise instance from type of class

Tags: class, swift, initialization

I am faced with an issue regarding porting objC code to Swift.

What I'm trying to do is to allocate and init an object from a class type.

This is how i do in ObjC

```
-(id)getExistingVCFromClass:(Class)classVC
{
    return ([dict objectForKey: NSStringFromClass([classVC class])]);
}


-(void)storeExistingVCForClass:(id)referenceToVC ForClass:(Class)classVC
{
    [dict setObject:referenceToVC forKey:NSStringFromClass([classVC class])];
}

-(void)retrieveObject:(Class)classVC
{

        //check if we have a previous one
        id existingVC;

        if ((existingVC = [self getExistingVCFromClass:classVC]))
        {
           //i retrieved some object matching the class
        }
        else
        {
          // found nothing -> init a new instance
            id newVC= [[classVC alloc] init];
            [storeExistingVCForClass: newVC ForClass:classVC];
        }
}
```

This is working perfectly.in ObjC.

Now in Swift I have this :

```
func getExistingVCFromClass(type:AnyClass) -> AnyObject?
    {
        return (dict?.objectForKey(NSStringFromClass(type)));
    }

func storeExistingVCForClass(object:AnyObject, type:AnyClass)
    {
        dict?.setObject(object, forKey: NSStringFromClass(type));
    }

func retrieveObject(type:AnyClass)
    {
        var myObj:AnyObject?;

        myObj = self.getExistingVCFromClass(type);


        if (myObj == nil)
        {
           // not found -> init , but i dont know how!!
            let newObject:AnyObject = type(); -> not compiling
            let newObject:AnyObject = type.new(); -> not compiling
        }

    }
```

I can't find how to init my new instance if I provide the class. How can I solve this in Swift ?

Also, in objC i didn't have to send any parameter to the init, because the .xib file was loaded automatically with the viewcontroller.

In Swift, it seems it doesn't load automatically the .xib file, so I add those inits to all my viewcontrollers

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)
    {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nil)
    }
```

and I have to instantiate my viewcontroller like this (giving in parameter the nib filename):

```
let myVC = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil);
```

So I would need to

- 1) Instantiate from an anonymous class
- 2) Give it some parameter

Any hint on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thx.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049673/swift-class-introspection-generics ?