# Accessing class type from instance

Tags: swift

I can't seem to find a way to do it. In Objective C it's possible using:

```
someInstance.class.SomeComputedClassVariable
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049673/swift-class-introspection-generics), but there's a compiler error stating `Class_Name does not have a member named SomeComputedClassVariable`, even though it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to the [mentioned post](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455).

```
someInstance.dynamicType.SomeComputedClassVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `reflect` to get the class name of an instance:

```
class SomeClass {
}

println(reflect(SomeClass()).summary)
```