# Class as Function Parameter

Tags: swift

Is it possible to pass a class as a function parameter? I currently have a base class which I'll refer to as `BaseClass`. Right now, here's what I can do:

```
func someFunction(instanceParameter: BaseClass) {
    // code
}
```

The parameter would be some class that inherits from `BaseClass`. However, I would like to pass a class type itself as a parameter. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
func someFunction(classParameter: Class) {
    // code
}
```

The parameter would be `ClassThatInheritsFromBaseClass` instead of an instance of `ClassThatInheritsFromBaseClass`.

On top of that, would it be possible to restrict the class parameter to classes that inherit from `BaseClass`? The pseudo-code below shows what I mean.

```
func someFunction(classParameter: BaseClass_Class_Not_Instance) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: This can be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049673/swift-class-introspection-generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [metatype type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455) - `.Type`:

```
func someFunction(classParameter: Class.Type) {
    // code
}
```

You may be able to restrict to only subclasses using generics, but I haven't tested this just yet:

```
func someFunction<T: BaseClass where T != BaseClass>(classParameter: T.Type) { ... }
```